# How to view clipboard on mac with all formatting

Tags: macos, unix, clipboard, copy-paste

How can I view the clipboard on a mac with all formatting applied? For example, if I copy-paste a table in Excel, not only does it copy the text, but it also copies formatting (I believe it copies it as an html object to the clipboard). How would I view this? The closest I have found is the `Finder Clipboard` or `pbcopy` but that seems to just show raw text, and no actual ancillary formatting. In other words, I want to view the literal data in my clipboard, not just the text that would be pasted into a plain text edit. How could this be done?

```
# this data should have formatting...
$ pbpaste
2019    Q1
2018    Q1
```

Comment: This looks relevant... https://superuser.com/a/1591637/363732

Answer (score 2):

get this tool.
https://langui.net/clipboard-viewer/

And yes, text copied from excel is "html format" like below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, this tool taught me a lot about clipboards on modern OS versions and led me to the right research material online, too.

Seems copying from many applications adds multiple entries (HTML, PLaintext or others) into the clipboard and an application can somehow report, which variants they can accept